# How use sleep in vimscript just for command-line bar?

Tags: bash, vim, command-line, vi, vim-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin for vim with `vimscript` and I want to show some log
for specefic time. like:

```
echo 'some log'
sleep 2
redraw!
```

When I use `sleep` and `redraw`, all of current window freezing for a while but I want sleep just for logs, not all vim window!
How can I do that?

Comment: It's good to know that you got an answer on SO. But if your question is vim specific, you may find better/more answers at http://vi.stackexchange.com, which is a dedicated site or `vi(m)` questions. (I am not discouraging you to ask questions here. But since you even offered bounty, I think it was urgent for you. Hence the suggestion.) Good luck!

Comment: @anishsane Oh I forgot it. That's a good idea, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sleep` will always block. With VIM version 8 you can use `timer` instead. Here is a stripped down example should not block VIM:

```
echo 'some log'
let timer = timer_start(2000, 'LogTrigger', {})
func! LogTrigger(timer)
  silent! redraw!
endfunc
```

Comment: I think `timer_start(2000, 'LogTrigger', {})` is correct, because when you set `repeat : -1`  that works forever and `redraw!` works multiple time and after call function multiple time, you can't see anything!